# Building a <ul> list on from js file

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to create the following code from the js side, because I am not sure how many of the list items to be printed and i need to set the data-ids from backend... But basically the output needs to look like this;

```
<ul id="myList">
<li><a data-id="Prev" href="#">Prev</a></li>
<li><a data-id="1" href="#">1</a></li>
<li><a data-id="2" href="#">2</a></li>
<li><a data-id="3" href="#">3</a></li>
<li><a data-id="4" href="#">4</a></li>
<li><a data-id="Next" href="#">Next</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Well, first you can, then maybe, but it might be this other way like. If you want us to fill in the blanks, please fill in those in your question. `:)`

Comment: In the meantime, take a look at the [Quirksmode DOM introduction](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
// Lets say you get this array from ypur backend..

var arr= ['Prev' , '1','2','3','4','Next'];

var html = '<ul id="myList">';

for(var i =0;i<arr.length ; i++){
    html +=  '<li><a data-id="' + arr[i] + '" href="#">'+arr[i] + '</a></li>' ; 
}

html += '</ul>';

// Append to your div

$('#list').append(html);
```

[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/hJswU/)

Comment: Backbone was referenced, but was jQuery? I didn't see it.

Comment: @JaredFarrish [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) uses either Zepto or jQuery as a dependency, and more often then not it's probably jQuery. At any rate both the OP's question and this anwser don't really have anything to do with Backbone.js.

Comment: @Jack - Possibly, hence the "fill in the blanks" request I posted under the question.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I saw your comment (you'll notice I also requested some more details) I was mainly pointing out that while the OP didn't mention they were using jQuery it is still "fair" to post a anwser that uses jQuery since the OP is most likely has it included. However as you noted there still quite a few blanks in the question.

Comment: @Jack - I didn't say it was pointless. This "disagreement", however, is.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I didn't really there was a disagreement, I was just trying to clarify my comment...